# Solana account rent/fee determination

Tags: account, fees

If I create a Solana wallet account via Rust by using instruction solana_program::system_instruction::create_account(...)
The 3rd parameter is the nr. of exempted amount of lamport, in the end it's SOL. Do I need to pay this amount or only need to mention the rent exempted number?
If I need to pay the equivalent amount of SOL then how to pay that?

```
//Build instruction for create account 
let create_token_acc_ix = solana_program::system_instruction::create_account(
    &payer_pubkey,
    &wallet_pubkey,
    rent,
    space as u64,
    &spl_token::ID,
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the call to use with your RPC connection object using the `space` var you've defined in your question:

```
let rpc_url = String::from("https://api.devnet.solana.com");
let connection = RpcClient::new_with_commitment(rpc_url, CommitmentConfig::confirmed());
    
let rent = connection
        .get_minimum_balance_for_rent_exemption(space)
        .unwrap();
```

And then your account creation follows...

When you then construct the transaction with the instruction you specify the payer.

There are full examples in the cookbook... search 'Solana Cookbook' and look at the "Accounts" reference.